# How to place both listview and textview in one page in android?

Tags: android

I am displaying a `TextView` and below that a `ListView` in one page. My code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/widget"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/widgetlay"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        >
    </TextView>
   </RelativeLayout>


   <ListView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/listlist" 
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1.0">
</ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here I am displaying the `ListView` data dynamically....but in my emulator it is displaying a `TextView` at the top and then the `ListView` with scroll...It is not expanding the list and instead it is scrolling with the content which is generated dynamically...Please tell me how to expand the entire `ListView`....

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try putting everything inside Scroll View.

Comment: listview already extends scroll so no need to put listview inside scrollview.

Comment: @ghost : it is very forbidden to put a listview in a scrollview

Comment: @njzk2: Sorry for the wrong advice. Will keep in mind this fact from next time.

Comment: @ghost : see this post from romain guy http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/2d1a4b8063b2d8f7

Comment: @Sweety could u please post some of your ListActivity? cos, it is possible that u might miss only one line of code..

Comment: Hi I have changed my code ...pleae check and tell me where I am going wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <LinearLayout android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TextView 

        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="status" 
        android:id="@+id/txtvw1">
    </TextView>

    <ListView 

        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:id="@+id/listlist"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtvw1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="status" >
</TextView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listlist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error here

`<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listlist" //error here
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</ListView>`

the ListView is filled of the LinearLayout
so that you can't get the TextView.

instand of this
you can layout your view as follows:

```
<ListView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/listlist" //error here
android:layout_height="0"
android:layout_weight="1.0>
```

**android:layout_weight="1.0"** //this will make the list view filled with the rest of the screem

Further more
I suggest you use "match_parent" instand of "fill_parent"
this WAS CHANGED in the SDK level 8...

Comment: hi i have changed my layout plz check once...this time it is not displaying the list after textview...only the textview is displayed..plz tell me where theproblem is...

Comment: OK, now you use the RelativeLayout install of the LinearLayout

Answer (score 1):

OK, now you use the RelativeLayout install of the LinearLayout
So you should add the relationship with your views in your layout.
 
You can layout as this:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/widgetlay"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" >
</TextView>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listlist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/txt1" />
```

**android:layout_below="@id/txt"----Indicate the relationship with the layout**
The RelativeLayout does not have the attr "orientation" and "layout_weight". So I don't suggest you to use this layout, It can't be fixed with the screen height in that way.

The good layout is:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtvw1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="status" >
</TextView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listlist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" />
```

Further more, what do you want to layout your views?

Answer (score 1):

This is a part of my work. List view will appear in the middle of your screen and what ever u need at the top, put it in place of header() and things that u need in bottom of the screen , put it in place of footer(). U can use relative layout instead of the linear layout

Hope this helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    >
     <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/layout_header">
    <include layout="@layout/header"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:gravity="center" android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  android:id="@+id/layout_footer">
        <include layout="@layout/footer" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"  android:layout_below="@id/layout_header"  android:layout_above="@id/layout_footer" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="visible" /> 

<!-- <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />  -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Dont use scroll for list views.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is meaning of expanding meaning here, but listView in scroll view dont behave normally. To resolve this issue you need to implement list view outside of scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you mean, but if you want to have the textView scroll with the content of the listView, you need to add it as a header in your listView.

Moreover, it is not a good idea to put a listview in a scrollview, the listview being scrollable, it messes with the scrollview mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You can NEVER ever place a listview in the SCrollView.
It wont behave properly.
Instead of it try using 
 *LinearLayout 
 TextView 
ListView 
 < /Linearlayout>*